# how to get only the words recognised by sphinx

Tags: java

i am using live speech recogniser
it recognises some word but i need only these worlds as output but the console shows 
please do say how to avoid it.

```
  public class Indian {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
    configuration.setUseGrammar(false);

     LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new     LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    System.out.println("Start speaking. \n");
    SpeechResult result;
     long timer=0;

 while (timer < 2*60*1000) {
result = recognizer.getResult();
if (result != null) {
           for(WordResult word : result.getWords()) {
            System.out.println("You said: " + word + '\n');
        }
}
  else {
            System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
        }
 }
 recognizer.stopRecognition();
      }
        }
```

my current output

```
  You said: {<sil>, 0.999, [1060:2170]}

   You said: {known, 0.999, [2180:2660]}
```

Required output:

```
You said: i am a java student
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reformat the output. Right now you are printing them on each line, and you are using the generic `toString` of the class `WordResult`.

Try something like the following :

```
public class Indian
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
        configuration.setUseGrammar(false);

        LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        System.out.println("Start speaking. \n");
        SpeechResult result;
        long timer = 0;

        while (timer < 2 * 60 * 1000)
        {
            result = recognizer.getResult();
            if (result != null)
            {
                System.out.print("You said: ");
                for (WordResult word : result.getWords())
                {
                    if (!word.isFiller())
                        System.out.print(word.getWord() + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
            }
        }
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u seb but now the output is like You said: <sil> that <sil> is  i need only that is how to avoid that <sil>

Comment: Ok, that's a filler token. You need to avoid printing those. I will edit.

Comment: There. I added a check, so we print the word only if it is not a filler.

Comment: ya now it is working but accuracy is 0% can u give me some suggestion to increase accuracy]

Comment: You should post a new question on that, I am not sure how sphinx works particularly. You may need to do some machine learning.